# adding hashmap object to internal memory every time

Tags: android, storage, internal

i have a hashmap object which i am saving in Internal memory, but each time its replacing the hashmap object instead of adding, how can i add the hasmap object each time when i call this method:

here is my code:

```
public void saveDataInInternalStorage(Context context, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hashMapObject,
        String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(context.getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE), fileName);
        // if (file.exists()) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        outputStream.writeObject(hashMapObject);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        // }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

The `true`tells the FOS to append the content to the file, not overwrite ist.

Comment: ok initially my hasmap will receive ("a",1) ("b",2) now next time i send ("c",1) ("d",2)... so wen i iterate it will i get all these values with your code?

Comment: You didn't post any iterating code. Maybe you just read the first line from file or something.

Comment: this is my code :Iterator itr = testStats.entrySet().iterator();
     while (itr.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
         System.out.println("KEY "+pairs.getKey() + " VALUE = " + pairs.getValue());
     }